# How to match a comment node with the Jsoup selector api?

Tags: java, css, jsoup

Here is a small HTML code:

```
<ol class="annotations">
  <!-- START ANNOTATIONS -->
  <li class="annotation">
     Foo
  </li>
  <li class="annotation">
     Bar
  </li>
  ...
  <!-- END ANNOTATIONS -->
</ol>

<ol class="annotations">
  <li class="annotation">
     Baz
  </li>
  ...
</ol>
```

I want to match the first `ol` node only.
Here is what I did:

```
Document d = Jsoup.parse(...);
Elements findings = d.select("ol.annotations");

if ((findings.size() != 0) && //
    (findings.first().html().startsWith("<!-- START ANNOTATIONS -->"))) {
     // Found !
} else {
     // Not found !
}
```

How can I achieve that using a single CSS query?

**Jsoup 1.8.2**

Comment: Are you sure you used `ol.notes`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic My mistake. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I achieve that using a single CSS query?

You can't, because there are no [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) for comment nodes.

A couple of issues with the way you're currently doing it:

1. Your HTML has `ol` elements with the class `annotations`, but your code is using a `ol.notes` selector.
2. (This may or may not be an issue, in a quick test it looks like [for my test, on my document] JSoup trims the string. It probably shouldn't be, but...) On the first match, you're calling `html()` and then using `startsWith` — but the HTML probably starts with some whitespace that you haven't allowed for.

Other than the correct selector, I'd probably look specifically for the comment node:

```
Element firstMatch = findings().first();
Node firstChild = firstMatch == null || firstMatch.childNodes().size() == 0 ? null : firstMatch.childNodes().first();
if (firstChild != null && firstChild instanceof Comment && ((Comment)firstChild).getData().indexOf("START ANNOTATIONS") != -1) {
    // Yes, it's there
}
```

That's just sort of thrown-together, but you get the idea. The second line in particular is a bit more awkward than I'd like, I'm **very** surprised to see that JSoup's [`Node`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html) doesn't have a `firstChild` accessor. It's a fairly basic part of the DOM API, and makes that line more awkward than it needs to be.

Comment: I think your point 2. is not valid, since html() is a method of Jsoup and will not give the original html string back but one generated form the parsed DOM. That means there is no whitespace before the first element.

Comment: @luksch: I had to test it to be sure. It looks like JSoup is trimming the string, which it probably shouldn't be. If the DOM is parsed from HTML that has whitespace after the `>` of the `ol`'s start tag and before the comment, that whitespace is the first node (a text node) in the `ol` and should be included in the `innerHTML` of the element ([and is on browsers](http://jsfiddle.net/z22jqeeh/1/)). But when I tested it with JSoup, it seems to trim that whitespace. I wouldn't rely on it not being there without more research.

Comment: I guess Jsoup build the output of ```html()``` by the DOM and text nodes are  created using  http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text-- And this states that the text is trimmed and normalized.

Comment: @luksch: No, I doubt that's what's being used to build the HTML string.

Comment: Actually `ol.notes` is  a mistake I did when I wrote the question. I really use `ol.annotations`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: This is not possible, since comments are not mapped to Elements in Jsoup, but [CSS selectors](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) work on [Element](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html)s. However, comments are [Nodes](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html) in the DOM tree and they can be identified be their name property: `node.nodeName().equals("#comment")` is true for comments. Of course this does not help you much, if you want to create a one-liner identifying your node with comment.